# Find words in txt list from a word with missing letters

Tags: php, string, char

Searching how to do this from some days so far but without success.
I've done a script to find words in a list containing some letters only once. It works.

Now i'd like to make a script to find words in a txt file list, with a word like this for example : W???EB??RD?. Positions of each letter are important. I just need to find words thats fit in. Missing letters are ?.

Could someone help me ?

Done this so far :

```
    $letters = "[A-Z]HITEBOARDS";
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('test.txt'));

$fl_array = preg_grep("[A-Z]HITEBOARDS", $array);

echo $array[0];
echo $array[1];
echo $array[2];
echo $array[3];
var_dump($fl_array);
```

Comment: Your regex pattern is missing the delimiters `/[A-Z]HITEBOARDS/`  And you should use `$array = file('test.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)` instead of file_get_contents and explode, which is dependent on the type of line endings in the file.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I've some difficulty to understand regex. It work, thank you ;)

Comment: Does that mean that your problem is solved?

Comment: Looks to me like you want some kind of levenstein calculation. Or something like it.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments your regex was missing the delimters

```
$fl_array = preg_grep("[A-Z]HITEBOARDS", $array);
```

Should be

```
$fl_array = preg_grep("/[A-Z]HITEBOARDS/", $array);
```

You may or should include the word boundary `\b` before and after a word, this will prevent matching partial words such as (for example) if you had this `/\b[A-Z]here\b/`  which could match `therefore` instead of just `there`.  Without the boundaries matches could happen in the start, middle or end of partial words, which is probably not what you want.  The boundary will match anything that is `\W` or in other words not `\w` or simpler `[^a-z0-9_]` or in English: matches anything not alpha, number or the underline, basically all your punctuation , special chars (except `_` ) and whitespaces.

So to put that in code would be this:

```
 $fl_array = preg_grep("/\b[A-Z]HITEBOARDS\b/", $array);
```

Also instead of:

```
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('test.txt'));
```

You can use

```
$array = file('test.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

The `file` function is preferred because it breaks the file into an array based on the line endings (not dependent on OS `\r\n` vs `\n` as explode is).  Besides that an better performance it also has two really useful flags.  `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` is a given as this removes the line endings which are normally retained in the array by `file()`.  The `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` will do basically what it says and skip lines that are empty.

Cheers.